# Run external program from R expecting user input

Tags: linux, r

I have an external program called `GPOPSIM_for_linux` that I would like to run from R. The program expects user input in form of the name of a parameter file. Suppose that `MyParam.txt` is its name.

Issuing `printf 'MyParam.txt' | /home/domi89/GPOPSIM/GPOPSIM_for_linux` in the shell works fine, but when I try

```
> cmd <- "printf 'MyParam.txt' | /home/domi89/GPOPSIM/GPOPSIM_for_linux"
> system2(command = shQuote(cmd))
sh: 1: "printf 'MyParam.txt' | /home/domi89/GPOPSIM/GPOPSIM_for_linux": not found
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up with the working directory...
Also, as hinted by Pafnucy, I need to use `system()` instead of `system2()`

It now works:
`system("cd ./data; printf 'MyParam.txt' | /home/domi89/GPOPSIM/GPOPSIM_for_linux")`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect issue is with `system2` that requires command and arguments to be separated. While with original `system` function you can use

```
system('ls -al')
```

with `system2` syntax is

```
system2('ls', args = '-al')
```